# Trouble saving a downloaded file to the desktop in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

When I use:

```
  WebClient web = new WebClient();
  web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChangedWeb);
  web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.website.com/Webs.exe"),
                            Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + @"\Webs.exe");
```

...Nothing downloads.

But if i change it to"

```
  WebClient web = new WebClient();
  web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChangedWeb);
  web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.website.com/Webs.exe"),
                            Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + "Webs.exe");
```

Then It downloads, but I get a file named "desktopWebs.exe". So How can I save a file to the desktop?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is this...

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Webs.exe";
```

Otherwise you are just tacking on the word desktop instead of the actual path.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Path.Combine

```
web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.website.com/Webs.exe"),
                        Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Webs.exe"));
```

This function will automatically insert (or remove) slashes as well as adapt to any file system being used

You should also consider using Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory, this points to the actual physical location of the desktop folder on the disk.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, That doesn't work. maybe because I'm using WPF?

Comment: SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory?

Comment: SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory doesn't work for me either. I get 'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' does not contain a definition for 'Combine'

Comment: that is the wrong Path class, that is the one used for drawing, I meant System.IO.Path

Comment: That will work only if I use KDiTraglia solution. Thank you for your help.